# Return only matching array item instead of all document values in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search, magento2

I'm new to Elasticsearch. I'm faced with unexpected behaviour with my client's search page result and my investigation has ended up in the ES structure.

I have a document field `name`, which has this mapping:

```
"name": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "sort_name": {
            "index": false,
            "type": "keyword"
        }
    }
}
```

So, usually, it has one value, so in this case, it matches a query correctly. But sometimes I have a document, which has an array of product names, which leads to fetching all of the array values into the search page result.

For example, if I have a product, which looks like this:

```
{
    ...,
    "name": [
        "Tesla",
        "Model",
        "XXX"
    ]
}
```

So, when I search this on `name`:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name": "Tesla"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": 150,
    "sort": [
        {
            "_score": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "stored_fields": [
        "_id",
        "_score"
    ]
}
```

It returns this:

```
"hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "magento2_product_4_v2",
            "_type": "document",
            "_id": "99999",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "name": [
                    "Tesla",
                    "Model",
                    "XXX"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When I needed only `Tesla`.

As a result, I will have 2 different products (imagine that `Model` and `XXX` are products), that users didn't search.

I would really want to avoid structure changes if that's possible since the new index is created automatically during reindex process (I'm using Magento 2 right now), so could you help me with the query?

Answer (score 0):

You have 1 document in your index magento2_product_4_v2.
This is

```
{
    ...,
    "name": [
        "Tesla",
        "Model",
        "XXX"
    ]
}
```

after request you get this document because this doc suits your request.

May be you want create 3 docs?

```
{
    ...,
    "name": [
        "Tesla",
    ]
} 


{
    ...,
    "name": [
        "Model"
    ]
}


{
    ...,
    "name": [
        "XXX"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you your comment. To be honest, I don't really want to correct process of creating documents or edit structure of index fields. since platform (Magento 2) takes care of this internally.
So, I afraid to make a reverse bug, when with fixing my issue I will break something behind.  Also, I should be responsible for compatibility during future upgrades if breakable changes will be released. But, I think, if there is no another option, I should get it done by this way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in elasticsearch without changing the mapping. You have a few options. such as using a nested or object field type.
You can also simply postprocess the results with regex, depending on how many ES features you're using to get the match in the first place.

Here is a potential mapping that you could use, assuming you know which specific field you want to search on.

```
"name": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "make": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "model": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "trim": {
            "type": "keyword"
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could write a query like this:

```
{
   "match": {
        "name.make": "Tesla"
   }
}
```

However, depending on the mapping and the data, this can not be enough in many cases, for example with arrays, due to the way elasticsearch flattens objects at index time. The other option would be to use a nested field type, which can ding performance on the search side. To me, this sounds like something that warrants revisiting the data modeling/es mapping side of things to get the search functionality you're looking for. Read more on the [nested mapping type here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.2/nested.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could use highlights. Update your query to:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name": "Tesla"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": 150,
    "sort": [
        {
            "_score": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "stored_fields": [
        "_id",
        "_score"
    ],
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "name": {
            }
        },
        "fragment_size": 300,
        "order": "score",
        "pre_tags": [""],
        "post_tags": [""]
    }
}
```

The response would look like:

```
"hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "magento2_product_4_v2",
            "_type": "document",
            "_id": "99999",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "name": [
                    "Tesla",
                    "Model",
                    "XXX"
                ]
            },
            "highlight": {
                "name": [
                    "Tesla"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You can't avoid returning the complete array of values in the _source portion of the response but the highlight section will be filtered to elements that matched the query.